# Only Display a # of Characters in Twig

Tags: twig

I am very unfamiliar with twig. Here's what I have:

```
{% if wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_website').0 %}
<tr>
    <th>{{ wp.__('Website', 'aviators') }}:</th>
        <td><a href="http://{{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_website').0 }}">{{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_website').0 }}</a>
        </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

I need to restrict this output to 35 characters without killing the link. It needs to still be active but only display 35 characters, plus ideally it would end with... to designate that the url is cut off but that's a bonus. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html is what you are looking for

**EDIT**

Just found that Twig has an extension called `text` it includes the `wordwrap` filter that is **exactly** what you're looking for

Link: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need but I can't get it right exactly. How would you place the the wordwrap function around the code I have? I tried slice too all different ways but no luck. either would make me happy but wordwrap would be perfect. Did I mention Im a newbie and this is my first time using github. I realy don't know enough to take that and run with it. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own Twig Extension. It's very easy.

First you must create the file with the filter code:

```
<?php
//Acme/AcmeBundle/Twig/AnExtension.php
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Twig;

class AnExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
                new \Twig_SimpleFilter('cutText', array($this, 'cutTextFilter'))
        );
    }

    public function cutTextFilter($text, $size = 50)
    {
        if (strlen($text) > $size)
        {
            return substr($text, 0, $size) . '...';
        }
        else
        {
            return $text;
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'an_extension';
    }
}
```

Then edit the *services.yml* file from this bundle, located at: */Acme/AcmeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml* and add:

```
services:
    acme.twig.an_extension:
        class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Twig\AnExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

and now you can use the filter in your code:

```
<a href="http://{{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_website').0 }}">
    {{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_website').0 | cutText(30) }}
</a>
```

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html